# How to convert javascript Buffer to array of byte for c/c++ API?

Tags: javascript, c++, buffer

I have a nodejs application and need to convert a Buffer object to array of byte as c/c++ API's payload. I tried "Uint8Array" and "Array.prototype.slice.call", but it seems they don't work as expect. The API could not decode them correctly.
Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I made a mistake before. After retest, to convert Buffer to Uint8Array which could be passed to c/c++ API as array of byte.